# Auto Copy and Paste Cell Values not Formula to another Cell

Tags: excel-formula

I also need to get your help for the same issue. I need to copy the cell values and not the formulas automatically to the other Cell, "automatically" meaning, I don't need to click, use mouse, or any other means to do that, like once theres a value on that specific cell (which is derived from a formula), the value will automatically be copied and pasted in the other cell (without any intervention from my part) (Only the value is copied not the formula)

Note:
The cell should contain only the copied value and not the formula.

Scenario:

A1 Cell : has 250 value

B1 Cell : has a vlookup formula to search for the value of A1 cell (I need to use VLOOKUP as there's a lot of items in the list, and it is "Dynamic", the reason I cannot just use formula "=A1" to get the value directly)

C1 Cell : Needs to copy and paste only the plain value from B1 cell which is 250, not including the vlookup formula, it should be automatically copied without any intervention (Cannot use VBA code / Macro as it will be run in excel online)

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

Just use abasic Excel formula.

---

Example:

The source data is in cell `A1`.

You want to copy the same value to cell `B1`.

In cell B1 write:

```
=A1
```

That is all.

---

Additionally, you need to configure correctly the strategy for calculating the formulas:

[image]

Comment: Hi @Virolino,

Thanks for your response, but
This will show "=A1" in cell B1 when you double click the cell, I only need the value not the formula.

Comment: Set the cell to type "Generic". After you edit the formula, press F9. Press F2 to modify the formula, make no change, press enter to accept. Press F9 again. There must be a bad configuration of Excel somewhere.

Comment: Wait a second: you want to use a formula, but not use a formula?! Why not use copy / paste? Otherwise, you will need to use a VBA script to detect changes to the source cell, and then copy only the value to the destination cell. Why do you need this kind of behavior, if I may ask? It is quite unusual.

Comment: Hi @Virolino,

What I need is exactly what you've mentioned for F9, converting the cell data to a value, but I need it to be automatic rather than doing the pressing of F9, F2 etc. Thanks

Comment: Basically, I hv 2 Sheets, 1st is the "Raw Data" Sheet" where i have a vlookup formula on each cell to search and get the value of specific criteria Ive set from another sheet "MSForms" which is from microsoft Form (This was being field up by users). I want to create  chart based on the vlookup values I got, I created a Chart, and use these table as the data source, but found out that Chart cannot read values from Formulas, so What im thinking is if I can copy just the "values" from these cells and paste it in another cell, and that is what I will use as a data source for my Chart.

Thank you

Comment: You complicated the problem a little, but the idea is the same. Use "=B1". The "vlookup()" will be hidden. You cannot have something automatic in the way you describe.

Comment: "Chart cannot read values from Formulas" - of course! That is why the formulas have to be calculated first. Be careful: Excel can be configured for automatic calculation of formulas (whenever a cell's content changes) or manual - no calculation is done until somebody presses F9. I am not familiar with the online variants of Excel, but you need to look for this option and set it to automatic. The you will not need to copy anything anywhere, just use the results of "vlookup()".

Comment: Hi Virolino,
It is what ive did, use the results of vlookup from the chart, but it doesnt read it. Even though it is already calculated in the cell, example, the cell shows 250 value, but when you double click the cell, it will show "vlookup etc etc"

Comment: I added to the answer. You need to change the configuration, I assume. Choose "On change" - hopefully it will do what you want. You may need to press F9 once after the change, not more.

Comment: I managed to find a solution, sharing as might help someone in the future, just needed to use =value(A1), instead of just "=A1", when I did this, the chart can read the values as it is and not the formula behind it. Found another work around as well, by using the formula =A1+0, for some reason this works too.

Comment: I used Excel for many years and I never needed "value()". Even currently, I work to generate charts from stuffy formulas, and "value()" is still not needed. I am glad that you found a solution, though.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to find a solution, sharing as might help someone in the future, just needed to use =value(A1), instead of just "=A1", when I did this, the chart can read the values as it is and not the formula behind it. Found another work around as well, by using the formula =A1+0, for some reason this works too. –

Comment: I am curious about this: try `=value(vlookup(...))`. Will anything change? You will less cells and less formulas. Or any formula instead of vlookup(), for that matter

Answer (score 0):

`=value(A1)` works perfectly , If that formula contains a `%` figure , simple We can multiply by `100` to get the correct value.